# Clip-path in IE11

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-11, clip-path

I'm trying to draw a star using clippath, but the shape appears as a simple square in IE11. Is there any solution to this?

https://jsfiddle.net/sleepydada/mh4bcbcf/

HTML:

```
<div id="image-wrapper">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
<svg id="svg-defs">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-triangle" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points=".5 0, .65 .35, .98 .35, .69 .58, .79 .91, .5 .7, .21 .91, .28 .56, .02 .35, .34 .35" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  clip-path: url(#clip-triangle);
}
```

Comment: add a height, width and viewbox to your svg! that should fix it

Comment: IE only supports clipping SVG elements, you just can't clip HTML elements.